# Receiving passed String

Tags: android

I have a string that I passed from an activity that looks this

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {   
                ......

                String searchTerm = et.getText().toString().trim();         
                Intent in = new Intent(PassingString.this, RecieveString.class);
                in.putExtra("TAG_SEARCH", searchTerm);
                startActivity(in);
```

In my other activity this is how I receive this string and encode it to my web address.
(`et` is just my editText in case you where wondering)

```
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
             ....

                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com"+ query + "json";
```

I am trying to move the code to receive this string out of my `doInbackGround` method it is slowing things down its just that when I move `Intent in = getIntent();String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");` under `onCreate` I get an syntax error underneath `searchTerm` (the one that is in the asynctask) that says "searchTerm cannot be resolved to a variable". I had tried declaring  `Intent in = getIntent();String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");` has `final` but it doesn't change anything. I have even tried putting it in in `onPreExecute` but it still doesn't change anything. So can somebody please help me solve this killer syntax error

here is the activity where I am receiving the string

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        

        Intent in = getIntent();
        String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");

        questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

    mTask = new LoadAllData();

         mTask.execute();

        }    

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {              
        /** If user Pressed BackButton While Running Asynctask
            this will close the ASynctask.
         */
        if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
        {
            mTask.cancel(true);
        }          
        super.onBackPressed();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

     if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
     {
        mTask.cancel(true);
      }  

        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

     if (pDialog != null)
     {
         if(pDialog.isShowing())
         {
             pDialog.dismiss();
         }
            super.onPause();

      }  
}

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();             
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();           
}
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {  

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {

                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com"+ query + "json";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();

                    json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return json;           

            }
```

Comment: It will help if you add your revised code blocks, so we can more clearly see and follow your changes.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to define a field inside one method and use it in another method, which is an incorrect use of [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).  Define the field at the class level and you can use it in both methods - assuming your AsyncTask is an inner class of this Activity (that it is in the same file).

```
private String searchTerm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    [...]
    searchTerm = getIntent().getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    [...]
    String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for posting the code - the way you have it set up, you should just pass the string as a variable to the execute method.  Then you can access it in the doInBackground method by accessing the args array:

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    [...]
    String searchTerm = args[0];
    String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
}
```

Comment: If they are in fact in two separate classes, I've frequently resorted to creating a third class consisting of `static` variables that I can use in any scope

Comment: You might run into problems doing that - in Android, there are plenty of ways to pass variables around to different components and to maintain state, and by using static variables, you run the risk of the variable being garbage collected while the app is idle, causing a crash when the user resumes the app.

Comment: do I have to make changes to the way I pass this string to the activity?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, are you still running into problems?  If you have a different problem, you should start a new question.